# How many relations can we form from A to B?

Tags: combinatorics

We have two sets for example: $A =  \{1,2,3,4 \}$ , $B = \{5,6,7,8,9\}$.

How many relations do we have from $A$ to $B$? (What is the formula?)

Comment: A relation is a just a subset of ordered pairs. So, how many ordered pairs $N$ are there? How many subsets can be formed from a set of $N$ elements?

Comment: Kfir, קבוצה is translated to set; whereas חבורה is translated to group. These two are very distinct objects.

Comment: The number of subsets that can be formed is the size of the "power set", this is cardinality $2^N$.

Comment: It is $2^{20}$ since it is the number of subsets of $A\times B$.

Comment: I'm not so sure that the number of relations from A to B equals the number of substets. Quite sure it isn't, truth be told...

Comment: @gebruiker Since a relation from $A$ to $B$ is, by definition, the same thing as a subset of $A\times B$, the number of relations equals the number of such subsets.

Comment: @and But this can not be an arbitrary subset I'd say. The point-set $(1,5)$ is a subset of $A\times B$, but it does not properly define a relation between $A$ and $B$. We can only have subsets in wich the whole of $A$ can be found somewhere in the first entry of the tuple $(\cdot,\cdot)\in A\times B$. Or perhaps I'm not using a proper definition for "relation"...

Comment: @and For the record, I'm assuming a "relation" means the same as a function from $A$ to $B$....

Comment: @gebruiker "Relation" does not mean the same as "function".

Comment: My apologies. I was confused by the terminology then...

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks the translation confused me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that any relation is subset of $A\times B$.

$A\times B$ has $|A||B|$ elements (ordered pairs). In your case, $|A| = 4, |B| = 5$, so there are $20$ elements in $A\times B$.

The number of relations is thus the number of subsets of $A\times B$ (equivalently, it is equal to the number of elements in the powerset $\mathcal P$ of $A\times B$), and this is given by $$|\mathcal P(A\times B)| = 2^{|A\times B|} = 2^{20}= 1048576$$

Comment: Thanks, so if i got it right the number of relations from |A|=1 to |B|=5 would be 2^5 right? does it include the empty set ∅?

Comment: Yes, it includes the empty set (which would represent the empty relation). And yes, your comment is correct.

Answer (score 0):

A relation $R$ from $A$ to $B$ is a subset of the cartesian product $A \times B$.

The size of $A \times B$ is $20$. ($A$ has $4$ elements and $B$ has $5$ elements)

Number of relations $= 2^{20}$.